# How to View Production Logs in Phoenix Web Application Deployed using Edeliver?

Tags: logging, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, devops

After successfully deploying our app to a Virtual Machine using Edeliver & Distillery using these steps:
https://github.com/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/blob/master/production-deployment.md

The app runs: http://52.232.127.28/
[image: phoenix-app-running]

However when we attempt to visit the "Posts" route: http://52.232.127.28/posts
we see an `internal server error`:
[image: phoenix-internal-server-error]

> As a phoenix *noob* I have *no idea* how to go about debugging the logs in Prod...

How do we see these logs on the Virtual Machine?
Where do logs go and can we `tail` the logs?

Comment: There should be a "log" folder in the directory you deployed your app to in the VM and it should contain the log files. Can you check?

Comment: Actually it should be in `var/log` inside the app dir: https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/ffbcba103442adf09efad11c33ce138d4632605c/priv/templates/boot.eex#L78-L81

Comment: @Dogbert thanks! in our case `/home/{username}/{appname}/var/log`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the latest version of Distillery, the logs [should be](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/97712f06f5bc31155c07c7a021a397abbfc32f7d/priv/templates/boot.eex#L75-L81) in the folder `./var/log` inside the release's root directory (the value of `DELIVER_TO` in edeliver).

Comment: Is there a way to change the name of the file? It defaults to `erlang.log` ...